# Selecting an autocomplete input value goes to a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like my website to load a new page depending on what a user selects from an autocomplete field. For example, if you select 'School of Arts' a page with information on the school loads, but a different page loads if you select 'School of History'.

So far I have the autocomplete working and written a function to go to a different page depending on what option you select, but it doesn't actually go to the page yet.

There aren't any errors in the console, so I'm not sure how to locate which part of my code is wrong.

Thanks

```
function autocomplete(inp, arr) {
  var currentFocus;

  inp.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
      var a, b, i, val = this.value;

      closeAllLists();
      if (!val) { return false;}
      currentFocus = -1;

      a = document.createElement("DIV");
      a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
      a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");

      this.parentNode.appendChild(a);

      for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase()) {

          b = document.createElement("DIV");
          b.innerHTML = "<strong>" + arr[i].substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>";
          b.innerHTML += arr[i].substr(val.length);
          b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i] + "'>";
          b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
              inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
              closeAllLists();
          });
          a.appendChild(b);
        }
      }
  });

  inp.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
      var x = document.getElementById(this.id + "autocomplete-list");
      if (x) x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
      if (e.keyCode == 40) {
        currentFocus++;
        addActive(x);
      } else if (e.keyCode == 38) { //up
        currentFocus--;
        addActive(x);
      } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (currentFocus > -1) {
          if (x) x[currentFocus].click();
        }
      }
  });


    function button(text) {
      var string = "";
      document.getElementById("tags").value = 'Go to your Department';
      text  = text.toLowerCase();
      switch(text){  
          case 'kent school of architecture':
              string = 'architecture';
              break;
          case 'school of arts':
              string = 'arts';
              break;
          case 'school of english':
              string = 'english';
              break;
          case 'school of european culture and languages':
              string = 'ecl';
              break;
           case 'school of history':
              string = 'hist';
              break;
          case 'school of music and fine art':
              string = 'mfa';
              break;
          default:
              string = '';
          }
          if (string != ''){
          window.location.href = "https://"+ string;    
    }
    else{
      window.location.reload();
    }
  };

  function addActive(x) {
    if (!x) return false;
    removeActive(x);
    if (currentFocus >= x.length) currentFocus = 0;
    if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = (x.length - 1);
    x[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");
  }

  function removeActive(x) {
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
    }
  }

  function closeAllLists(elmnt) {
    except the one passed as an argument:*/
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      if (elmnt != x[i] && elmnt != inp) {
        x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
      }
    }
  }

  document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
      closeAllLists(e.target);
  });
  }

var schools = [ "Kent School of Architecture","School of Arts","School of English","School of European Culture and Languages", "School of History", "School of Music and Fine Art"];

autocomplete(document.getElementById("tags"), schools);

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#tagsautocomplete-list').click( function() {
    var text = document.getElementById("tags").value
    document.getElementById("tags").value = 'Go to your Department';
    button(text);
  })
});
```

My html:

```
<div class="input-group">
              <input name="tags" id="tags" autocomplete="on" class="form-control ui-autocomplete-input form-control-md" type="text" placeholder="Enter your school name...">
    <div id="tagsautocomplete-list" class="autocomplete-items"><div><strong>School of Art</strong>s<input type="hidden" value="School of Arts"></div></div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is the `.click()` working? You didn't post `#tagsautocomplete-list` so we can't test it.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be. I've added it in now

Comment: For the sake of everyone's sanity, don't use `string` as a variable name

Comment: @user3005003 just to be clear, you want the redirect to happen when the user selects one of the autocomplete values that show up?

Comment: Yes Bojan, if they select one of the autocomplete values it should redirect them to another page. A different page for each value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I did it:

```
  function button(text) {
  var string = "";
  document.getElementById("tags").value = 'Go to your Department';
  text  = text.toLowerCase();
  switch(text){  
      case 'kent school of architecture':
          string = 'architecture';
          break;
      case 'school of arts':
          string = 'arts';
          break;
      case 'school of english':
          string = 'english';
          break;
      case 'school of european culture and languages':
          string = 'ecl';
          break;
       case 'school of history':
          string = 'hist';
          break;
      case 'school of music and fine art':
          string = 'mfa';
          break;
      default:
          string = '';
      }
      if (string != ''){
      window.location.href = "https://kentunion.co.uk/"+ string;    
}
else{
  window.location.reload();
}
};


function autocomplete(inp, arr) {
  var currentFocus;

  inp.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
      var a, b, i, val = this.value;

      closeAllLists();
      if (!val) { return false;}
      currentFocus = -1;

      a = document.createElement("DIV");
      a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
      a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");

      this.parentNode.appendChild(a);

      for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase()) {

          b = document.createElement("DIV");
          b.innerHTML = "<strong>" + arr[i].substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>";
          b.innerHTML += arr[i].substr(val.length);
          b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i] + "'>";
          b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
              inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
              closeAllLists();
              button(inp.value);
          });
          a.appendChild(b);
        }
      }
  });

  inp.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
      var x = document.getElementById(this.id + "autocomplete-list");
      if (x) x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
      if (e.keyCode == 40) {
        currentFocus++;
        addActive(x);
      } else if (e.keyCode == 38) { //up
        currentFocus--;
        addActive(x);
      } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (currentFocus > -1) {
          if (x) x[currentFocus].click();
        }
      }
  });




  function addActive(x) {
    if (!x) return false;
    removeActive(x);
    if (currentFocus >= x.length) currentFocus = 0;
    if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = (x.length - 1);
    x[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");
  }

  function removeActive(x) {
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
    }
  }

  function closeAllLists(elmnt) {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      if (elmnt != x[i] && elmnt != inp) {
        x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
      }
    }
  }

  document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
      closeAllLists(e.target);
  });
  }


var schools = [ "Kent School of Architecture","School of Arts","School of English","School of European Culture and Languages", "School of History", "School of Music and Fine Art"];

autocomplete(document.getElementById("tags"), schools);
```

You had a syntax error in `except the one passed as an argument:*/`. The comment was not opened properly.

I removed the `.click` because it is no longer necessary (see below).

Your `.button()` function was defined inside your `.autocomplete()` function, so the `.click()` could not call it.

I moved the `.button()` function outside the `autocomplete()` function in case you want to use it, though my solution should still work even if you leave it where it is.

Finally, I changed the code to call `.button()` inside `b.addEventListener("click", function(e)` because that will cause the redirect right after the `tags` field get populated.

Side note: as WillardSolutions mentioned, please don't use `string` as a variable name ;).